# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 [Java]

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, wamp

I'm trying to add music CD information to a DB with an application. When the button is clicked it will write out the information to a WAMP DB. I keep getting an error and I've looked and couldn't find the solution to my problem.

```
Driver loaded
SQL error during INSERT
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
```

Those are the errors that I'm getting

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //this runs when the submit button is pressed
    String artistName = txtName.getText();
    ...
    String format = "";
    if (rdbtnCd.isSelected()) {
        format = "CD";
    } else if (rdbtnVinyl.isSelected()) {
        format = "Vinyl";
    }

    String query = "INSERT INTO cds VALUES ('" + artistName + "','" + albumTitle + "','" + recordLabel + "','" + genre + "','" + year + "','" + format +"');";

    try {
        //  Connection c = DBClass.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("SQL error during INSERT");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here's my connect as well

```
private void connect() {
    try { //Login details for the DB.
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/music";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    } catch (Exception e) { //Error is DB connection is unsuccessful .
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot connect to database server");
        // System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database connection established");

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What about the error message isn't clear?  You supply six values but your table does not have six columns.  Also, you shouls be using prepred statements.

Comment: (1) Learn to use parameters for inserting values, rather than munging the query string.  (2) List all columns explicitly in an `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are providing not as much data as the table cds do contain columns. And now the DB engine does not know in which columns to put your data.

To overcome this you must provide the names of the columns you want to fill. Example:

```
insert into cds(column_name1, column_name2)
values (1, 3)
```

Look up the table definition and see which columns you want to fill.

And insert means you are inserting a new record. You are not modifying an existing one. Use update for that.